# Leitor de QR Code ZXING no HTML - WEBQR

Tags: javascript, html, servidor, localhost, qrcode

estou tentando implementar o leitor na minha aplicação web assim como no site "webqr.com", copiei o site completo desde o index.html até os scripts(2). até ai tudo bem eu acesso o servidor atraves do localhost e funciona como na imagem a seguir
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas quando eu tento acessar atraves do meu IP ou de algum dominio ele não funciona:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

repare que não foi solicitado o uso da camera. o que pode estar interferindo no funcionamento?

Comment: Você já deu uma olhada no console? Retorna algum erro|alerta|exceção?

Comment: @LauroMoraes obrigado pela dica, encontrei o erro. vou publicar

Answer (score 1):

apos abrir o console do navegador encontrei o erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

traduzindo o erro, ele precisa do certificado HTTPS pra receber a media do usuario(webcamming)

Comment: você pode usar um certificado auto-assinado em localhost... se for do tipo "wildcard" no Windows Chrome versão **57.0.2987.133** e inferior não lança alerta pois lê o certificado do repositório local (assumindo que esteja instalado no "Repositório de Autoridade de Certificação Raiz) já Firefox, Opera e outros lançarão erro